# Unable to create Azure VM using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell, powershell-5.0

Using `PS 5. 0` on windows 10 I created an Azure Storage account and an Azure Service. Got the latest image name using the following command. But when I run the following command to create a VM I get following error:

**PS Command to get the latest image:**

```
$images = Get-AzureVMImage `
| where { $_.ImageFamily -eq “Windows Server 2012 Datacenter” } `
| Sort-Object -Descending -Property PublishedDate

$latestImage = $images[0]
$latestImage
```

The above command ran successfully and gave me the image name as: `a699494373c04fc0bc8f2bb1389d6106__Windows-Server-2012-R2-20171017-en.us-127GB.vhd` that I used in the following command for creating a `VM`.

**PS command to create VM**:

```
New-AzureVMConfig -Name "Server15" -InstanceSize ExtraSmall -ImageName "a699494373c04fc0bc8f2bb1389d6106__Windows-Server-2012-R2-20171017-en.us-127GB.vhd" | Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Windows -AdminUsername "MyAdmin" -Password "MyPsswd" | New-AzureVM -ServiceName "MyServiceName"
```

**Error**:

```
WARNING: No deployment found in service: 'MyServiceName'.
New-AzureVM : BadRequest: OSImage a699494373c04fc0bc8f2bb1389d6106__Windows-Server-2012-R2-20171017-en.us-127GB.vhd 
not found. If you are using a VM image, it must be specified as VMImageName for the role, not as SourceImageName for 
OSVirtualHardDisk.
OperationID : '498779aecff53369ac9e793da15c16c3'
At line:1 char:250
+ ... d "D7v.oeiue4ieiur" | New-AzureVM -ServiceName "MyServiceName"
+                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureVM], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.PersistentVMs.NewAzureVMCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script works for me, here is the output:

```
PS C:\Users\jason> New-AzureVMConfig  -Name "Server16" -InstanceSize ExtraSmall -ImageName "a699494373c04fc0bc8f2bb1389d6106__Windows-Server-2012-R2-20171017-en.us-127GB.vhd" | Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Windows -AdminUse
rname "jason" -Password "xxxxxxx" | New-AzureVM -ServiceName "jasontest321"

OperationDescription OperationId                          OperationStatus
-------------------- -----------                          ---------------
New-AzureVM          05a8d386-ac4b-3843-8fe4-1018325112a3 Succeeded
```

Please check your Azure PowerShell version, for now the latest version is `5.0.1`, my Azure PowerShell version is `4.4.1`, that script works fine, maybe we should upgrade your Azure PowerShell.

We can download [Azure PowerShell 5.0.1 installer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/download/v5.0.1-November2017/azure-powershell.5.0.1.msi) to your Windows 10 and install it, then test it again.

More information about Azure PowerShell Version, please refer to this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases).

Hope this helps.